# Create not repetable structure inside ngFor or something like ngForOutlet

Tags: angular, ngfor

How to create some structure inside ngFor that will not be repeated? I need something like ngForOutlet.
I want to group items depending on some item property and then insert them in suitable div.

To better show what i want to achieve, here's some pseudo code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someData">
    <div>
      <h4>Group A</h4>
        <div *ngForOutlet *ngIf="item.group === 'a'">
            <div>
                {{item.brand}}
                {{item.model}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Group B</h4>
        <div *ngForOutlet *ngIf="item.group === 'b'">
            <div>
                {{item.brand}}
                {{item.model}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

All items from group A will be inserted in div under Group A heading and all from B under Group B.

@Edit:
Currently i have something like this, but i want to group it:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someData">
    <app-some-card #card [brand]="item.brand"></app-some-card>
</div>

<button (click)="onClick()">test</button>
```

**.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren('card') cards: QueryList<SomeCardComponent>;

  someData = [{...},{...},...];

  onClick() {
    this.cards.forEach(card => {
        card.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend structuring your model to match your requirements.

In your component, once you have retrieved `someData`, loop through it and add items to relevant groups.

component.ts

```js
someData: any[];
groupA: any[];
groupB: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.someData = [{
    group: 'a'    
  }, {
    group: 'b'
  }, {
    group: 'a'
  }];

  this.groupA = [];
  this.groupB = [];

  this.someData.forEach(item => {
    if (item.group === 'a') {
      this.groupA.push(item);
    } else if (item.group === 'b') {
      this.groupB.push(item);
    }
  });
}
```

It is then simple enough to bind to these groups in your HTML.

component.html

```html
  <div>
    <h4>Group A</h4>
        <div *ngFor="let item of groupA">
            <div>
                {{item.brand}}
                {{item.model}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4>Group B</h4>
        <div *ngFor="let item of groupB">
            <div>
                {{item.brand}}
                {{item.model}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i have component in ngFor and item data is passed to that component in every iteration, then i can have ViewChildren and easily call one method from every component. If i do as you say i will need to have many ViewChildren objects and iterate through every one of them to call method from every component

Comment: That changes the question - quite an important fact to miss out... Can you update your question with an example of what you mean.

Comment: I updated my question. I also would like to somehow listen to events from whole QueryList of components and count them

Comment: I still don't understand why this stops you grouping the items in your model? `QueryList` still works when the references are distributed throughout the HTML https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sukuuw